# How to get a string from a Reader?

Tags: io, go

In the [strings](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/) module, there is a function [func NewReader(s string) *Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader) to create a `Reader` from a string.

How can you get/read the string from the `strings.Reader`?

Comment: Are you asking how to read one string from the `Reader` or how to get the original string from the `Reader`?

Comment: Both of them, I'm new to go tying to understand basic `io` concepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ioutil.ReadAll](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) :

```
bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
// err management here
s := string(bytes)
```